# Binding kinetics of 6xHis-Tag

Tags: biochemistry, protein-binding, literature

For the planning of an experiment I would like to know the binding kinetics (k<sub>on</sub> and k<sub>off</sub>) of a 6x-His-tag to a Ni-NTA surface.

I know they should differ due to surface quality and position of the His-tag in the protein. But maybe there is some literature out there (that someone of you knows) from which one could get at least a rough estimate of the kinetics.

Comment: What sort of research have you done so far? Both Entrez PubMed and Google Scholar have very good search functions.

Comment: It seems I didn't look thoroughly enough at the results PubMed and Scholar returned yesterday. Hope it helps someone in the future…

Answer (score 1):

Some more hours of literature research finally produced a result:

As published by [Khan et al. 2006](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac060184l) 6x-His-tag has two distinct dissociation constants of **k<sub>off1</sub> = 6.3 10<sup>-3</sup>** and **k<sub>off2</sub> = 1.8 10<sup>-3</sup>**.